# Kusto : Summarize count by hours of the day (hours in column)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a list of metrics that I want to visualize by name (row) and count by hours of the current day (column)

The example below create a row by Hour and metric name

```
customMetrics
| extend hour= floor( timestamp % 1d , 1h)
| where name contains "WebServiceCall-"
| summarize event_count = sum(value) by hour, name
```

I want the data display like this:

```
MetricName | Count Hour0 | Count Hour2 | Count Hour3 | ... | Count Hour24
```

Is it possible to do it with Kusto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [pivot plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you Avnera

```
customMetrics
    | where name contains "WebServiceCall-"
    | extend Hour= floor( timestamp % 1d , 1h)
    | project name,  Hour, value
    | evaluate pivot(Hour, sum(value))
```